# Browser Inconsistencies: Working around FORM submission differences

Tags: html

https://jsfiddle.net/516amfmL/2/ -- click into the form input, press ENTER

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">

  <button style="display: none !important;" onclick="alert('!! Should NOT see this !!');">Hidden Button</button>

  Click in input, press ENTER: <input type="text" />

  <p>
    <button onclick="alert('this is okay');">Visible button</button>
  </p>

</form>
```

When running the above JS Fiddle, Chrome & Firefox work the same, MS Edge & Safari do things differently.  I listed this as a bug in Chrome, and was quickly told that they were following the HTML standard which states:

> 4.10.22.2 Implicit submission -- A form element's default button is the first submit button in tree order whose form owner is that form element.

No one thought to make it clear in the standard if it should ignore hidden elements.

Anyways, that's not my question.  My question is what's the best way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A hidden button on a form is still active and has always been this way, but it's natural to think it would or should be automatically disregarded.

One possible fix to your problem is to change the first button to an `<input type="button"/>`

```
<input type="button" style="display: none !important;" value="Hidden Button" onclick="alert('!! Should NOT see this !!');"/>
```

This works on Chrome and Edge.

Here's your [fiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/516amfmL/3/).